# PHPSpreadsheet collapsing for grouped rows

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

I tried to create 3 outline levels in Excel file (with PHPSpreadsheet), which is being filled this way:

```
$worksheet=$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$colCount=$stmt->columnCount();
$rowNo=$worksheet->getHighestRow() + 1;
$object =  (object) $arrFinal;
foreach ($object as $row)
        {
            $colNo = 0;
            foreach ($row as $element)
            {
                if ($colNo < 6)
                {
                    //nothing to do here now
                }
                else
                {
                    $worksheet->getRowDimension($rowNo)->setOutlineLevel(0)->setVisible(false)->setCollapsed(true);
                    if (($colNo == 28) && ($row['AcceptDate'] != ''))
                    {
                        $value = date('d.m.Y', strtotime(substr($row['AcceptDate'],0,10)));
                    }
                    else
                        $value=$element;

                    if (is_null($value)) $value=''; $worksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($colNo-5,$rowNo,$value);
                    if ($row['Level'] == 2)
                    {
                        $worksheet->getRowDimension($rowNo)->setOutlineLevel(1)->setVisible(false)->setCollapsed(true);
                        $worksheet->getStyle('A'.$rowNo)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER_COMMA_SEPARATED2);
                    }
                    if ($row['Level'] == 2 || $row['Level'] == 1)
                    {
                        $worksheet->getStyle('A'.$rowNo)->getAlignment()->applyFromArray( [ 'horizontal' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER] );
                    }
                    if ($row['Level'] == 3)
                    {
                        $worksheet->getRowDimension($rowNo)->setOutlineLevel(2)->setVisible(false)->setCollapsed(true);
                        $worksheet->mergeCells('A'.$rowNo.':O'.$rowNo);
                        $worksheet->mergeCells('Q'.$rowNo.':Z'.$rowNo);
                    }
                }
                $colNo++;
            }
            $rowNo++;
        }

    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setAutoFilter(sprintf("A4:%s%d",Coordinate::stringFromColumnIndex($colCount-6),$rowNo-1));
```

Everything is working OK except one thing - these groups of rows are not hidden and collapsed, when I check the file after filling with data. However, if I just do this:

```
$worksheet->getRowDimension(1)->setOutlineLevel(0)->setVisible(false)->setCollapsed(true);
```

right after

```
$spreadsheet=IOFactory::createReader('Xlsx')->load('templates/FB.xlsx');
```

it works as intented.
What am I doing wrong here? Tried to search for similiar questions, but didn't find helpful explanation for such cases. Maybe missed something.

P.S. Added some code to original test case (setAutoFilter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, my bad, didn't realize that I had `setAutoFilter` after data filling, which was overriding the results of `setVisible(false)->setCollapsed(true)` usage in `foreach`, setting all rows visible again. To avoid this behaviour, I just placed filtering

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setAutoFilter(sprintf("A4:%s%d",Coordinate::stringFromColumnIndex($colCount-6),$rowNo-1));
```

before `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is easier the rows not to create in the result excel.
Maybe a [Filter](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/autofilters/) is the solution that you are looking for. One Note to this there is only one filter per worksheet possible. PHPSpreeadsheet don't support pivot tables and auto table formatting.

Answer (score 0):

#### To remove protection for setOutlineLevel or Grouped rows

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setFormatRows(false);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setFormatColumns(false);
```